# National identification number in DS-160

Tags: visas, usa, j1-visas

I am in the process of applying for a J-1 visa, I am Italian and I legally reside in Belgium since 2016. In the DS-160, it is asked to provide the national identification number. I have two: one from Italy, which was assigned to me at birth; and one from Belgium, which was assigned to me when I first arrived here. Which one should I use?

Answer (score 4):

I presume you are applying as an Italian citizen and giving Italian passport details, so you should use your Italian ID number for consistency.

The fact that you have a Belgian ID number is not really relevant to the visa application process.